# The integral $\int_E \sin (\frac{1}{x-1})$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $E$ be the open interval $(0,2)$. Does the Lebesgue integral $\int_E \sin (\frac{1}{x-1})$ exist?

I would say no because the integral would exist if and only if $f(x) = \sin(\frac{1}{x-1})$ is measurable. Let $E = E_1 \cup E_2$ where $E_1 = (0,1]$, and $E_2 = (1,2)$. Then the set
$$F_0 = \{x \in E_2: f(x) > 0\}$$ has infinite measure (this can be seen easily by drawing the sine graph).

Actually I am a little confused here. The Lebesgue integral is defined to exist if $\int_Efdx$ is finite. In this case I proved that it cannot be finite because the function on the interval $E_2$ itself has infinite measure. But does having infinite measure still imply that $f$ itself is a measurable function?

Comment: The set $S = \{x > 0 : e^{-x} > 0\}$ also has infinite measure, yet $e^{-x}$ is still integrable over $(0,\infty)$. Also: a set having infinite measure is not the same as a set being nonmeasurable. Also, your set $F_0$ is a subset of $(1,2)$ and must therefore have *finite* measure - do you mean to say that there is infinite area under the graph and above the $x$-axis? This too would be incorrect, as $\sin$ is bounded and therefore the area underneath is at most $1  \cdot 2$, the area of a rectangle of height $1$ above the interval $(0,2)$.

Comment: The integral $\int_0^2 \sin (\frac{1}{x-1})\,dx$ exists in the Riemann sense, provided you supply some value (any value) at the point $x=1$.  Peculiar historical feature of the Riemann integral that the definition insists on being defined at *all* points.   So this is a calculus problem that a student of measure theory should dismiss.  After all the Lebesgue integral does include the Riemann integral.  (As an aside it does not include the improper Riemann integral, but that is not an issue here since the integrand is bounded.)

Comment: *Anecdote:*  I remember hearing of a student on a PhD comprehensive asked to calculate the Lebesgue integral $\int_0^1 x^2\,dx$ and starting to panic.   When you study the Lebesgue integral  some students forget entirely all their previous knowledge about integration.  By the way the answer is $\frac13$.  Ask any calculus student.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should expect that the integral *does* exist, as $f(x) = \sin(1/(x-1))$ is bounded and continuous almost everywhere; such functions tend to be very nice to integrate (they are, in particular, measurable). A function which is not integrable is *either* nonmeasurable *or* there is infinite area under its graph.

In fact, the shape of the graph suggests that $f(x)$ is odd-symmetric about $x = 1$ (i.e., $f(1 - x) = -f(1+x)$; you can confirm this algebraically) and therefore $\int_E f(x) \ dx$ should be $0$.

Comment: Would it be correct to then argue by saying that the sets $$F_\alpha = \{x \in E_1: f(x) > \alpha\} \cup \{x \in E_2: f(x) > \alpha\}$$ are measurable for all $\alpha$? I think I got confused between nonmeasurability and having infinite measure.

Comment: It would be correct to say that $F_\alpha$ as you have defined it is indeed measurable for every $\alpha$. Better yet, each $F_\alpha$ is an open set, because it can be seen to be a countable union of disjoint open intervals. But none of the $F_\alpha$ sets have infinite measure, as they are all subsets of $(0,2)$ by definition, which has finite measure.

Comment: @RobBland No need for the union to be countable or disjoint: any union of a family of open sets is open.

Comment: No need for it, but it happens to be a countable union in this case.

Comment: That's fine then. I prefer to make it clear for the OP or other readers, as it might be misunderstood as being a condition for this to apply.

Comment: It is countable because sine is a $2\pi$-periodic function right? So in fact $F_\alpha$ is just a union of such intervals, all contained in $(0,2)$ and thus $F_\alpha$ are all measurable.

Comment: Maybe I should add that sine being continuous ensures that we do indeed get intervals.

Comment: You can see that $F_\alpha$ is measurable for two different reasons: in the first case it is the countable union of open intervals, and open intervals are measurable, and the countable union of measurable sets is measurable; in the second case, it is the union (countable or otherwise) of open sets, thus it is open, and every open set is automatically measurable.

Answer (score 2):

$f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \sin(1/(x - 1))$ for $x \neq 1$ and $f(1) = 0$ is easily shown to be Borel measurable due to the fact that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R} \setminus {1}$. To say that "$\int_{0}^{2}f(x)\,dx$ exists" means that either $\int_{0}^{2}f^{+}(x)\,dx < \infty$ or $\int_{0}^{2}f^{-}(x)\,dx < \infty$. In your case we have the even stronger fact that $\int_{0}^{2}|f(x)|\,dx \leq 2 \cdot 2 = 4$. Here we would say that the $f$ is integrable, which means that the integral exists and is not $\pm \infty$.

Comment: I was trying to do it by first using the result that $f$ is measurable iff $\int f$ exists. So I constructed sets $F_\alpha$ (see the comments in the other answer) and tried to show that they are all measurable. Because I can't be sure that even though the graph under the area is finite as you've mentioned, some $F_\alpha$ can turn out to be nonmeasurable. Honestly speaking though, I've never seen a question where this actually happens.

Comment: Ah maybe the continuity property is again the way to go... We do avoid nonmeasurable $F_\alpha$ this way.

Comment: @KelvinLian $f$ being measurable is not enough to ensure that $\int f$ exists. For example, $\sin : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, but $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(x)\,dx$ does not exist since both $\sin^+$ and $\sin^{-}$ intergrate to $\infty$.